# Unable to send funds from a Byron-era wallet created with Daedalus back in 2017

Tags: wallet, cardano-cli, cardano-node, daedalus, byron

This is not a situation that happened to me personally, so I am sorry upfront if I can't provide all the necessary information, but I am trying to help recover money from a wallet that has been generated with a very early version of Daedalus. The recovery phrase related to that wallet does not appear to be correct, thus the wallet can't be recovered through any wallet or the `cardano-wallet` CLI tool. (bad entropy, check the last word error). Since it was made with an old version of Daedalus, I am unsure of where the key files are stored. Nothing that I have ever gotten from Cardano-CLI/-wallet in the Daedalus folder (maybe it's stored somewhere else, or a different format back then?)

The main issue here is that Daedalus isn't able to send any transactions out, because the node is not letting the transaction through. Here is the error:

```
renderer.js:34 [2022-02-20T09:08:54.788Z] [daedalus.mainnet:error:ipcRenderer] {
    "msg": "AdaApi::createTransaction error",
    "data": {
        "error": {
            "code": "created_invalid_transaction",
            "message": "The submitted transaction was rejected by the local node. Here's an error message that may help with debugging: TxValidationErrorInMode (ShelleyTxValidationError ShelleyBasedEraAlonzo (ApplyTxError [UtxowFailure (WrappedShelleyEraFailure (MissingVKeyWitnessesUTXOW (WitHashes (fromList [KeyHash "ffea5f425e909556d3190f446ba1058609d2f459fe442932b93d2232"]))))])) AlonzoEraInCardanoMode"
        }
    }
}
```

Would it be in any way possible to recover the funds from that wallet? Alternatively, do you think there's any way to at least get the wallet key in a format that `cardano-cli` and `cardano-wallet` can work with? Maybe manually constructing a transaction could work in this case?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two types. Seed phrase or wallet created with cardano-cli. (I'm pretty sure you can still create a wallet with cli that uses seed phrases)

If the wallet was created using cardano-cli then you likely also need the verification key (.vkey) to build transactions and you need the signing key (.skey) to sign the transaction.

If you don't have either the correct seed phrases or the verification and signing key, you may not be able to recover these funds.

Comment: You can generate the verification key from the signing key with cardano-cli.